# Error "Segmentation fault" en C - Arreglos dinámicos en 2D entre archivos distintos

Tags: array, c, 2d

Necesito pasar arreglos dinámicos de 2D, comenzando desde la función main, hacia otra función que está en otro archivo, para finalmente retornar el resultado obtenido a la función main. 
Me ha funcionado con arreglos de tamaño pequeño, pero al utilizar arreglos de gran tamaño, el resultado al ejecutar el código me muestra este error:  "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

El "header"
(MIFUNC.h)

```
#ifndef MIFUNC
#define MIFUNC

int miFunc(int fila, int col, int arr[fila][col]);

#endif /* MIFUNC */
```

la función para modificar el arreglo 
(MIFUNC.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "MIFUNC.h"

int miFunc(int fila, int col, int arr[fila][col])
{
    int i, j;

    int (*salida)[fila] = malloc(sizeof(int[fila][col]));
    for (i = 0; i < fila; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            salida[i][j] = arr[i][j] * 4; //operaciones en el arreglo
        }
    }
    free(salida);
    return salida;
}
```

la función "main" 
(MAIN.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "MIFUNC.h"

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int fila  = 200;
    int col   = 200;

    int (*entrada)[col]   = malloc(sizeof(int[fila][col]));

    for (int i = 0; i < fila; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col ; j++)
        {
            entrada[i][j] = j; //agregar los datos
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fila; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col ; j++)
        {
            int (*salida)[col] = miFunc(fila, col, entrada);
            printf(" %d ", salida[i][j]); //mostrar el resultado
        }
    }
    free(entrada);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que la siguiente llamada a función fuese válida:

```
int miFunc(int fila, int col, int arr[fila][col]);
```

El valor de `col` debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación, lo cual es un poco complicado ya que es una variable.

Lo que tienes que hacer es usar punteros dobles:

```
int miFunc(int fila, int col, int** arr)

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int fila  = 200;
    int col   = 200;

    int **entrada = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*fila);
    for( int i=0; i<fila; i++ )
      entrada[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*columna);

    // ...

    for( int i=0; i<fila; i++ )
      free(entrada[i]);
    free(entrada);
}
```